# Add "0" to countdown timer after it reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

So basicly what I would like to do is have my countdown timer add a "0" once it reaches below "10". So far I have tried an if statement (In code below) which did not work. Here is my full code:

```
CountDownTimer('01/1/2017 12:0 AM', 'countdown');
  CountDownTimer('01/1/2017 12:0 AM', 'newcountdown');

  function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
  {
      var end = new Date(dt);
      var _second = 1000;
      var _minute = _second * 60;
      var _hour = _minute * 60;
      var _day = _hour * 24;
      var timer;

      function showRemaining() {
          var now = new Date();
          var distance = end - now;
          if (distance < 0) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
              return;
          }
          var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
          var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
          var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
          var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

          // THIS IS THE "IF" STATEMENT THAT DID NOT WORK, EVERYTHING ELSE IS WORKING
          if (seconds < 10) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '0' + seconds + '.';
          }

          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + '.';
      }

      timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: You are overwriting it just below the if...

Comment: You're adding the value directly to the element `.innerHTML`, then overwriting that after the `if`. Try `if (seconds<10) seconds = "0" + seconds;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is not the `if`, which is working:

```
if (seconds < 10) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '0' + seconds + '.';
}
```

But the fact that, just after that, you are overwriting the previous value:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + '.';
```

An easy solution is converting `seconds` to an string, in your `if`:

```
if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
```

This way, you can use the string in your subsequent `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
      // THIS IS THE "IF" STATEMENT....
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0"+ seconds;
      }
```

than to construct your output use:

```
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            hours + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            minutes + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            seconds + '.';
```

Also, your expiration should be at `<=0` not at `<0`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your If-statement is working correctly.  However, right after your If-statement you have

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

This is going to overwrite your previous declaration setting the innerHTML to `days + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'`.

Try setting your seconds in the If-statement so that the last line uses the updated seconds.